Show $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{4}{32}+\frac{5}{64}...=1$
Show $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{4}{32}+\frac{5}{64}...=1$.
This is a textbook question (from Haese IB Math HL 1) from the end of a chapter about sequences and series.
The formulas available from that chapter are

Sequence formulas $a_n=a_1+d\cdot(n-1)$ and $g_n=g_1\cdot r^{n-1}$.
Finite series formulas for arithmetic & geometric, and the infinite geometric series formula.

I came up with a proof, but it is slightly beyond the techniques I listed.
I listed out several partial sums:
$\frac{1}{4},\frac{4}{8},\frac{11}{16},\frac{26}{32},...$
and noticed that each has the form $\frac{2^n-n-1}{2^n}$. (Maybe lacking some detail, namely I should probably better demonstrate this pattern continues).
That fraction tends to a value of $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But, this notion of limits is beyond the scope of the chapter.
The series in the question seems resistant to some other methods from the chapter.
For instance: if I say $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{4}{32}+\frac{5}{64}...=T$
I wondered: can I write another equation by doubling everything, and somehow combine equations in such a way that most of the terms cancel each other out? This is how the book derives geometric series formulas (multiplying by $r$, not $2$).
Then I'd have $\frac{2}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\frac{6}{16}+\frac{8}{32}+\frac{10}{64}...=2T$
This was a dead end. Subtracting the equations puts me right back at the beginning.
It feels like I am missing some clever manipulation that the authors of the book intended.
Also, I don't have access to the solutions manual of the book.
I'm asking for a solution involving only the sequence and series formulas, and/or some kind of clever manipulation that cancels out most of the terms.

hint: write the general term, recognize the arithmetico-geometric sum; find its value using known methods

Can you say more about "arithmetico-geometric sum"? I know the numerators are arithmetic and denominators are geometric. I'm also not sure I know what you mean by shifting.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Yeah this question is definitely a duplicate.

Using differentiation on Geometric series:
The given series is of the form:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$$
Let's consider the geometric series:
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1 - x} \quad \text{for } |x| < 1.$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $ x $:
$$\frac{dS}{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}.$$
Multiplying both sides by $ x $:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^n = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2}.$$
Put $x=\frac{1}{2}$ on both side:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}} = 2.$$
However, the original series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$$
can be expressed as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = 1.$$
Thus, the summation converges to:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n+1}} = 1.$$
This shows that $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{8} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{4}{32} + \cdots =1$
Using infinite Geometric series
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{8} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{4}{32} + \cdots \\
& = \frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{32}\right) + \cdots \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \cdots\right) + \left(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{64} + \cdots\right) + \left(\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{64} + \frac{1}{128} + \cdots\right) + \cdots \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots\right) + \frac{1}{8} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots\right) + \frac{1}{16} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots\right) + \cdots \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 2 + \cdots \\
& = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots \\
& = 1
\end{aligned}

Here's a fairly elementary way to approach this:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k+1}} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1
}{2^{k+1}})= \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^m} = 1.
$$
where for the first equality we use the fact that $\frac{k}{2^{k+1}}=\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$. In the second equality we reorder the terms of the summation, and for the third and fourth equality we simply sum geometric series.
In order to justify the rearrangement of the summation, note that the terms of the double summation are all positive, and hence the series converges if and only if it is bounded above, and its limit is the supremum of the partial sums, independently of the order of summation.
